# tfignore Issue with new Ionic/Angular App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tfs

I'm having an issue with my tfignore file I created. All that is in the tfignore file is node_modules/ but below you can see that only some of the node_modules directory is excluded. Any ideas on why the whole directory is not excluded?

[image: Included NodeModules]

[image: Excluded NodeModules]

[image: tfignorelocation]

[image: Now excluded items]

Comment: Did you commit the `.tfignore` file? What is the content of `.tfignore`?

Comment: I have committed it. The only contents are
node_modules\

Comment: Are you using a local workspace? `.tfignore` files only apply to local workspaces, not server workspaces.

Comment: I am using local yes

Comment: Is the `.tfignore` file in the root of your repository?

Comment: I added a pic to the original question. Its at the root of the folder in which I created the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `\node_modules` instead of `node_modules\` in your `.tfignore` file.

Comment: I made that change and now it's excluding even less files when trying to add the files to source control. Picture 4 above shows the results now

Comment: You may try to exclude node_modules in the pending changes, to see whether it helps you.